# Php multi-dimensional array from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, resultset

I have a mysql table that looks like this:

```
id | id_transaction | id_item    | 
1  |  it0001        | T0001      | 
2  |  it0001        | T0002      |
2  |  it0001        | T0003      |
3  |  it0002        | T0001      |
4  |  it0002        | T0003      |
5  |  it0003        | T0003      |
6  |  it0003        | T0004      |
```

and I am trying to build a multi-dimensional array that would end up looking like this:

```
Array
(
    array('T0001','T0002','T0003'),

    array('T0001','T0003'),

    array('T0003','T0004'),

);
```

I am using the select query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id_item,id_transaction from transaction_item ")or die("<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: 1. don't use `mysql_*` it's deprecated+removed now. Use `mysqli_*` OR `PDO` for this 2. you din't did anything after query execution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.Don't use `mysql_*` it's deprecated+removed now. Use `mysqli_*` OR `PDO` for this

2.You din't did anything after query execution.

A `mysqli_*` version code is:-

```
 <?php
     $dbhost = 'localhost'; //change credentails
     $dbuser = 'root';//change credentails
     $dbpass = '';//change credentails
     $dbname = 'TUTORIALS';//change credentails
     $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$dbname);

     if(! $conn ) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
     }
     $sql = 'SELECT id_item,id_transaction from transaction_item';
     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
     $final_array = array();
     if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           $final_array[$row['id_transaction']][] = $row['id_item'];
        }
        echo "<pre/>";print_r(array_values($final_array));
     } else {
        echo "0 results";
     }
     mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: Ok,it worked, but how can i get a result without the id_transaction?
I have edited the question just now.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` in this manner:

```
SELECT id_transaction, GROUP_CONCAT(id_item)  
FROM transaction_item
GROUP BY id_transaction
```

This will result in the following:

```
+----------------+-------------------+
| id_transaction | id_item           |
+----------------+-------------------+
| it001          | T0001,T0002,T0003 |
+----------------+-------------------+
| it002          | T0001,T0003       |
+----------------+-------------------+
| it003          | T0003,T0004       |
+----------------+-------------------+
```

which you can then use php's `explode()` to create your arrays in the following manner:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $final[] = explode(',', $row["id_item"]);
}

print_r($final);
```

Doing it in this manner will give you **faster** results as PHP would only iterate 3 times to build your array.

Comment: I just don't understand the point of group concatenating something only to explode it again.

Comment: @Strawberry faster performance when you let SQL do the work. If not, youll end up iterating too many times with php. Not so obvious with small data sets but when you think of a big list, the difference is pretty clear

Comment: I suspect that the opposite is true.

Comment: but how can i get a result without the id_transaction? I have edited the question just now. Thanks.